# Starting point for Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I've noticed that :

- when writing some text in an `<input>` field with Google Places Autocomplete API on my desktop computer, the propositions are made in my local area (Orleans, France),
- when writing some text in an `<input>` field with Google Places Autocomplete API on my mobile, the propositions are made in Paris, France, *which is not where I am*.

This is probably due to implicit IP geolocation.

**How to force Google Places Autocomplete input field to "guess" the propositions in the area of a specified city?** (in my case: Orleans, because my website is dedicated to users of this city)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read up on "Location Biasing" in the [Google Places API docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing). You can add `location` and a `radius` parameter to the request to return results mainly from desired area.

So your request might look something like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=SEARCH_STRING&location=ORLEANS_LAT,ORLEANS_LNG&radius=RADIUS_IN_METERS&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

If you use `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` class, take a look at [this section of Google Maps JS API v3 docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Autocomplete). There is a `bounds` parameters which according to the docs:

> The area in which to search for places. Results are biased towards,
>   but not restricted to, places contained within these bounds.

It's also worth noting that in both API's there is a `components` or `componentRestrictions` parameter which allows you to restrict searches based on country. E.g.:

```
autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({country:'fr'}) //to restrict results only to France.
```

More on that in the linked docs.

Comment: I already have a `map` in my webpage, so I tried `autocomplete.setBounds(map.getBounds());` to set a preference/bias towards the current map bounds, but unfortunately, no change... Do you have an idea?

Comment: You have to set the bounds to the bounds of the area you want the results to be returned from. The bounds can be created like this: `new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(SOUTH_LAT, WEST_LNG), new google.maps.LatLng(NORTH_LAT, EAST_LNG));` So if your city is Orleans, France, something this should work for you `autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(47.832887461156986, 1.7125700205077692), new google.maps.LatLng(48.012343482282816, 2.1403501718749567)));`

Comment: Thanks! How would it be possible to totally restrict choices (not only a bias but a total restriction) to a specifc administrative region of a country?

Comment: So far, you can only restrict it by country. Check `setComponentRestrictions` method of the `Autocomplete` class. Try `autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({country:'fr'})` to restrict results only to France.